# Netsuite Custom Field with REGEXP_REPLACE to strip HTML code except carriage return

Tags: netsuite

I have a custom field with some HTML code in it:

```
<h1>A H1 Heading</h1>
<h2>A H2 Heading</h2>
<b>Rich Text</b><br>
fsdfafsdaf df fsda f asdfa f asdfsa fa sfd<br>
<ol><li>numbered list</li><li>fgdsfsd f sa</li></ol>Another List<br>
<ul><li>bulleted</li></ul>
```

I also have another non-stored field where I want to display the plain text version of the above using `REGEXP_REPLACE`, while preserving the carriage returns/line breaks, maybe even converting `<br>` and `<br/>` to `\r\n`

However the patterns etc... seem to be different in NetSuite fields compared to using ?replace(...) in freemarker... and I'm terrible with remembering regexp patterns :)

Assuming the html text is stored in `custitem_htmltext` what expression could i use as the default value of the NetSuite Text Area custom field to display the html code above as:

A H1 Heading

A H2 Heading

Rich Text

fsdfafsdaf df fsda f asdfa f asdfsa fa sfd

etc...

I understand the bulleted or numbered lists will look crap.

My current non-working formula is:

`REGEXP_REPLACE({custitem_htmltext},'<[^<>]*>','')`

I've also tried:

`REGEXP_REPLACE({custitem_htmltext},'<[^>]+>','')` - didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: I'm not "parsing" html, i want to remove html text. REGEXP_REPLACE is a perfectly good method to do this

Answer (score 0):

When you use a Text Area type of custom field and input HTML, NetSuite seems to change the control characters ('<' and '>') to HTML entities ('<' and '>').  You can see this if you input the HTML and then change the field type to Long Text.

If you change both fields to Long Text, and re-input the data and formula, the `REGEXP_REPLACE()` should work as expected.

Comment: One of the source fields is the webstore description {storedescription}. I'm not sure which type that field is.

Comment: That's a Rich Text field, which has similar wrinkles.  Are you entering the HTML in Formatted Edit Mode or Source Edit Mode?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have learned recently, Netsuite encodes data by default to URL format, so from < to `&lt;` and > to `&gt;`.

Try using triple handlebars e.g. {{{custitem_htmltext}}}

https://docs.celigo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038856752-Handlebars-syntax

This should stop the default behaviour and allow you to use in a formula/saved search.